# thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

Tags: android, exception

i am new to android app development ... all i am doing is to create a app that adds one to the counter wen add button is clicked  and sub one wen subb button is clicked . pls point out my mistakes

**startingpoint.java**`

```
package vignesh.pandian.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Startingpoint extends Activity {

    int counter;
    Button add, subb;
    TextView displ;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startingpoint);
        counter=0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        subb =(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        displ =(Button) findViewById(R.id.tex);

 add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                displ.setText("value is "+counter);

            }
        });
         subb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                displ.setText("value is"+counter);

            }
        });         


    }

}
```

**activity_startingpoint.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Add one " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/My"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Vignesh&apos;s app !!!!"
        tools:context=".Startingpoint" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tex"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="Value is"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        tools:context=".Startingpoint" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSub"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/add"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="Subract one " />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please give us the full stack trace of the exception

Comment: your problem solved ?

Comment: @vignesh your problem is solved, please accept answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TextView displ;
>
> displ =(Button) findViewById(R.id.tex);

This is wrong, use this

```
displ =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tex);
```

disp1 is Textview object, not button object.